# Is there a way to assign SIM cards to personal and work profile

Tags: dual-sim, android-enterprise

I recently had a problem with merging all the data from two phones (one personal and one for work) into a corporate owned personal work profile dual-sim phone.

Here, importing the contacts for the work profile was a problem. Importing via file, transferred via the work-profile OneDrive app did not work.
So, the next attempt was to store all contacts on the SIM card of the old work phone and move the (work) SIM into the new dual-sim phone.
However, the contacts stored on the (work) SIM show up in the personal-profile contacts only.

Is there a way to associate a SIM card with a profile?
E.g. SIM1 is personal and SIM2 is work, so that the personal contacts app only shows contacts stored on SIM1?
This would also apply to SMS, e.g. handling SMS received from the work SIM by the messages app of the work-profile.

Comment: A good question. On Reddit there are a few similar questions, but all of them I have found without answer.

Comment: @Robert, I also came across the unanswered Reddit questions, that's why I decided to post my question here. I suspect, that the workings of SIM and SMS are either too basic (the Android OS can not fully take control of them) or are too basic (the OS makers simply don't care).